# How should I read this python traceback/what is causing "breaks" in?

Tags: python, stack-trace

**I know what a key error is, and why I am getting it, this question is about what is occurring to the call stack not why I am getting a key error. I am also not looking to know exactly what's happening in the pandas operation specifically, but anytime I see a callstack that appears to be "divided"**

I have experience with C# and .net languages, but need some analysis and a friend suggested I use pandas in a jupyter notebook. I am trying to understand how to read a call stack generated by pandas when I have a key error. While doing so I found I don't understand why a traceback is formatted the way it is. I'd like to compare traceback A and traceback B and understand why A is behaving differently than B.

traceback A
[image]

traceback B
[image]

I understand every line of traceback B, it tells me exactly the order of calls and line numbers where my error is occurring. We go directly from one function call to another and only print out the exception name at the beginning along with the name and message at the end. What I don't understand is why we appear to reset the stack trace for the callstack in traceback A; I'm guessing maybe we catch the exception, print the traceback and then rethrow, but that's only a guess. What exactly is happening in the exception handling to cause this?

Comment: Traceback A happens when there's an exception handler in the internal code that raises another exception. You see the traceback of the internal exception and then the traceback of the exception that it raised.

Comment: In the case of Pandas, it has an internal hash table that raises `KeyError`. The handler for that raises another `KeyError`.

Comment: PEP 3134 defines the underlying functionality behind this reporting: https://peps.python.org/pep-3134/